# Standard error of linear fit parameters

Tags: fitting

I fitted data belonging to a MSD (mean squared displacement of a vibrating micrometer sized particle) by using a linear function:

```
data = {{0.0166667, 0.0000119831}, {0.0333333, 0.0000361185}, {0.05, 0.0000672071}, 
        {0.0666667, 0.00010521}, {0.0833333, 0.000142751}}; 

datalog = Log10[data];

model = a*x + b;
fit = FindFit[datalog, model, {a, b}, x]; 
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]];

Plot[modelf[t], {t, -2, -1}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[datalog]}, 
     PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"Log10 [y]", ""}, {"Log10 [x]", ""}}]
```

The result is:

[image]

`fit` yields the fittings parameters. From the slope one can calculate the diffusion coefficient.

To get the standard deviation of the fitting parameters I used:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[datalog, x, x];
lm["ParameterTable"]
```

which gives:

[image]

My **question**: Is there another possibility to obtain the errors of the fit parameters (from `FindFit`) without calling `LinearModelFit` and `ParameterTable`?

Comment: Why linearize when nonlinear regression capabilities are available? `FindFit[data, a x^b, {a, b}, x]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... how can I obtain the errors of the fit parameters (a,b)?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to avoid `LinearModelFit`/`NonlinearModelFit` in favour of `FindFit`?  What's wrong with `NonlinearModelFit`?  It also calls `FindFit` internally, but it also does additional calculations to get the errors.  You'll need to do these *manually* if you don't want `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @mrz - the easiest way would be to use `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`, but I take it you want the formula used to calculate these for academic purposes.  I'd look at [this page](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Stetson/Stetson2_1.html) and [this page](http://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-122/122E.pdf)

Comment: ...and if you do use `NonlinearModelFit[]`, you can use the `"ParameterErrors"` property of the resulting `FittedModel[]` object.

Comment: somebody dislikes this question: can he/she explain why - or is this just for fun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using fit as computed and formula for standard error [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption).

[image]

```
Clear[a, b];
{a, b} = {a, b} /. fit;
regressedpoints = a # + b & /@ datalog[[All, 1]];
n = Length[datalog];
errors = datalog[[All, 2]] - regressedpoints;
meanx = Mean[datalog[[All, 1]]];
Sqrt[(Total[errors^2]/(n - 2))/Total[(datalog[[All, 1]] - meanx)^2]]
```

> 0.0174645

Not sure about the other value.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd be iffy about concluding anything when the standard error computed here was derived from a linearization, which also distorts the errors in the data.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the same result for the slope as obtained by `LinearModelFit` ...

Comment: The standard error of the intercept (a) can be determined using the standard error of the slope (call it `seb`) as `sea = seb Sqrt[Total[datalog[[All, 1]]^2]/n]`.

Comment: I disagree with @J.M. that linearization "distorts the errors in the data".  While linearization should not be blindly applied, it many times makes the relationship more linear *AND* results in errors that more closely match what the fitting procedures (in their default mode) assume:  a constant variance for all values of the predictor.  My observation is that many responses on this site tend to ignore the error structure assumptions and the examination of residuals.  However, in this particular case with only 5 observations, there's not much one can do.

Comment: @Jim, since least squares is done under the assumption that errors in the data follow a normal distribution, a linearization transformation would result in something whose errors aren't exactly Gaussian anymore, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @J.M. No and Yes.  Suppose that $y =e^{a+b x+\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.  Then a linear model with normal errors results as $\log{y} = a + b x +\epsilon$.  And a least squares fit does not require that the errors follow a normal distribution.  If the errors do have a normal distribution, then the least squares estimators have certain optimal properties.